# Android Background Location Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-11

While asking for location permission in the background, it keeps asking me to open the settings menu and allow it, even though I say allow only this time. (Android 11)
I want to get permission on my login activity's init function.
I just don't want it to ask for permission again when I select only this time and start the app again.

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    } else {
                        askPermissionForBackgroundUsage();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                askForLocationPermission();
            }

        }
         private void askForLocationPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission Needed!")
                .setMessage("Location Permission Needed!")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 101);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Permission is denied by the user
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,

}, 101);
    }
}

private void askPermissionForBackgroundUsage() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission Needed!")
                .setMessage("Background Location Permission Needed!, tap \"Allow all time in the next screen\"")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 101);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // User declined for Background Location Permission.
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 101);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking again when you dont wanna ask again?

Comment: Android is not to let your idea. Because, when you ask a permission, if user not allowed permission and you can second ask your permission.  But last ask second permissons, android is not let your asking.

Comment: @blackapps how can i check if i asked permission before?  so i can use like this if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ifAskedBefore)

When use choose allow always or never ask again there is no problem but. I want button "allow only using app" to function same as button "never ask again"

Comment: Use shared preferences to indicate that you asked before.